# T-SQL Update Statement WHERE clause with table alias

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

Right I'm getting myself confused so just want to clarify, let's say I want to do the following update inside a trigger. The trigger is on a table called `tblCustomers`:

```
UPDATE tblContacts 
SET tblContacts.ContactName = I.ContactName
FROM tblContacts cont 
INNER JOIN inserted I ON cont.customerID = I.customerID
```

Will that only update the records from the `inner join` between `inserted` and `tblContacts`, i.e. in most cases just one record, or do I need to include a `WHERE` clause?

Also, am I OK to use the alias (cont) in the `where` clause or do I need to use `tblContacts`?

Sorry I know this is silly but I'm getting myself more and more confused! Thanks!

Comment: Why, do you want to do that at all?  Why do want to denormalize the data?  Why do you want to duplicate data.  Make a View.

Comment: We're catering for two types of customers, companies and individuals. When it's an individual there's still a candidate record, so we have a trigger that updates the Customer Contact name if the Candidate name is updated, and vice versa. Didn't want to convolute the question by providing all that context, and that's probably not saying enough. We have trigger based auditing running so we can always backtrack changes if we need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will that only update the records from the inner join between `inserted` and `tblContacts`, i.e. in most cases just one record

Yes. That can be one or multiple rows - depending on what your statement that causes the trigger to fire actually did - but it will only ever update those rows that are part of the `Inserted` table

> Also, am I OK to use the alias (`cont`) in the where clause or do I need to use `tblContacts`?

You can definitely use the table alias! In fact, when you define a table alias, you have to use it.

Comment: Thanks for that, been confusing myself so much! Thanks for clearing that up

Answer (score 1):

Your update query will update all `tblContacts.ContactName` values wherever there is a match per ON clause defined `ON cont.customerID = I.customerID`. So if 10 rows matches then 10 values (10 rows) will be affected.

Again, yes you can use the table alias in `WHERE` condition.